# scanf read integer input into uint8_t

Tags: c

Is there a way to use scanf to read an unsigned char decimal input into a uint8_t variable?

I am afraid if I read %hu or %u into a uint8_t, it may corrupt the adjacent memory because uint8_t is one byte, but %hu is 2 bytes, and %u is 4 bytes.

I am using MinGW32

```
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The code I am worried about:

```
/* worried.c - issue demo code. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint8_t filler1 = 17;             /* do not corrupt me please. */
    uint8_t my_mem;
    uint8_t filler2 = 39;             /* do not corrupt me please. */ 

    printf("please enter a number: $ ");
    scanf("%u", &my_mem);             /* corrupts fillers... */
    // scanf("%hu", &my_mem);         /* this also corrupts... */
    // scanf("%hhu", &my_mem);        /* still corrupts... */ 
    // scanf("%"SCNu8, &my_mem);      /* still corrupts... */
    // scanf("%"PRIu8 "\n", &my_mem); /* still corrupts... */

    printf("filler1 = %u.\n", filler1);
    printf("my_mem = %u.\n", my_mem);
    printf("filler2 = %u.\n", filler2);         

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code above does corrupt the fillers, which is catastrophic when reading into a struct which is going to be directly written into a binary(record) file later.

I could solve it by casting from a temporary variable, but that takes a little extra work for my program which I was wondering if I could avoid forcing my program to do, and read into my_mem directly.

To date, it seems the solution that seems most likely is:

> The only way to portably do this that works on GCC4.9.3 and newer is
>   through casting. There are more elegant solutions on GCC5.2 e.g. %hhu,
>   but they misbehave on GCC4.9.3.

Comment: `scanf("%" SCNu8, &my_mem);` (use `#include <inttypes.h>`)

Comment: I tried it, doesn't seem to compile. It also doesn't know what SCNu8 is even after importing the header.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is right. However, if you're just concerned about `scanf()`ing a type smaller than `short`, you can use `%hhu` to `scanf()` an `unsigned char`.

Comment: scanf("%hhu", &my_mem); mutates both fillers to 0 :\

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works fine with both `"%hhu"` and `"%"SCNu8`.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Does it conform to C99?  Prior to C99, the `hh` modifier syntax did not exist, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: use C99 compiler. (e.g gcc)  [DEMO](http://ideone.com/XSWYqx)  Do you use the MSVC?

Comment: I am using MinGW32 without C99 flag. Setting the C99 flag does not remedy turning both fillers to 0. doing "%"SCNu8 causes compilation error. EDIT: "%"SCNu8 DOES work with the C99 flag, but it still corrupts the fillers to 0.

Comment: use option with `-std=c99 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY just tried it, the fillers are still corrupted to 0. https://gyazo.com/2f8157a414478c607dcceb1a5b35f356 (ignore the directory name, it's COBOL for simulating COBOL structured record files). If you are curious, yes the two fillers are not 0 if I do not do any scanfs.

Comment: That causes it to just keep reading input after the number(doesn't terminate read on '\n') until i type in another character as well as newline. all of these do not work for me http://hastebin.com/xubuvawihi.pl. gcc.exe (GCC) 4.9.3.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I did, see the gyazo(https://i.gyazo.com/2f8157a414478c607dcceb1a5b35f356.png) image. Did I do something different there?

Comment: Apparently, it seems does not work `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`. It does not reproduce in my environment.

Comment: That's bothersome since it's a standard feature. I feel it'd be wrong to specifically create a new function to read up to 3 characters from stdin and cast it to uint8_t just to act consistantly across platforms.

Comment: Well you could always just avoid using MinGW ;)  Otherwise a simple workaround is to just read into an integer and cast.  When you want consistency across platforms, you're eventually going to have to make some concessions.

Comment: @paddy I could but it should not be a system specific issue because it's standard C, I trust the standard library more than writing my own implementation of these things, and the system should not matter because it's C. It should just let me know that Windows does not have support for %hhu. Otherwise I may as well go back to not trusting the standard library with anything they don't explicitly cover, which I guess is the correct default. I guess I better get started writed my own minimal c io wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

With a compliant compiler, use `SCNu8`  [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191212/scanf-read-integer-input-into-uint8-t#comment60017251_36191212)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

if (1 == scanf("%" SCNu8, &my_mem)) Oh_happy_day();
```

With a lesser compiler, get a new compiler or use what OP all ready knows.

```
unsigned u; 
if (1 == scanf("%u", u)) {
  my_mem = u;
  Oh_somewhat_happy_day();
}
```

Or define `SCNu8` yourself (it is a macro)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#ifndef SCNu8
#define SCNu8 "hhu"
#endif

if (1 == scanf("%" SCNu8, &my_mem)) Oh_happy_day_again();
```

Comment: Sadly having to check compilers inside the code makes it needlessly more complicated, and may as well just use casting. If this is the case, then the answer would be that there is no portable way of doing what I want, and I should always just cast.

Comment: @Dmitry I suspect your standard include files are lacking in more that just `SCNu8` and need many fixes.  Collecting those repairs in one include file and using that include is better than adopting weak practices throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a compiler bug.  This bug arises using MinGW in Windows because the default mode of operation for `scanf` calls is to forward the calls to the Microsoft C Runtime, which does not support `%hhu`.

There is a switch you can use with MinGW to use their own implementation of `scanf` and other such functions, instead of forwarding to Microsoft. If you compile with the following switches:

```
-std=c11 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO
```

then it may fix the problem.  With this compiler it is not standards-conforming by default, you have to supply various switches to get it to operate in standard mode.

I tested this with [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org) -- a modern fork of the defunct MinGW project -- and gcc 4.9.2, and it worked for me. YMMV

Comment: Wait, so it does work for you on gcc4.9.2 w64, but it doesn't work for me on gcc 4.9.3 w32? And MinGW manager doesn't have updates for it?

Comment: You are probably using the defunct MinGW instead of the current one (which is called mingw-w64).  The current one fixes bugs.

Comment: I just reinstalled it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/ using the "get latest version" link on top, the bug persists, and gcc version didn't change. Even with flags.

Comment: I've  reported the bug here https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2292/. Probably did it wrong(I put the wrong discussion link, but I added a note in discussion) but it's a learning experience.

Comment: @Dmitry that is the defunct one (for the third time)

Comment: Also check that you spelt the `_D` flag exactly right

Comment: -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO is how i wrote it.